# Update query failing using JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I'm trying to update a `mysql` table and insert a `json` array into a column (that currently contains a json array).

Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
$array = ['key1' => 'val1', 'key2' => 'val2'];
$array = json_encode($array);
// ...some time later:
$mysqli->query("UPDATE table_name SET colname={$array} WHERE somecol=someval");
```

This same sort of structure works fine when I'm using INSERT. Any ideas as to why this is not working with `UPDATE/SET`?

Comment: Are you escaping/quoting the JSON value? (Read up on prepared statements anyhow. Then switch to PDO). Ask $mysqli->error else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL is probably messed up when it gets to the database.
And the way you are using it defeats the purpose of using mysqli.

The generated query would look like this:

**UPDATE table_name SET colname={"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"} WHERE somecol=someval**

Because of the missing single quotes the insert would not work.

The recommended way to do it is below:

**Note:**

- Use PDO (recommended) or MySQLi in the way it was intended to be used.
- You'll have to do the error checking and stuff yourself

**Example:**

```
$sql = 'UPDATE table_name SET colname=? WHERE somecol=someval';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param('s', $someValue);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Touch I liked your answer a lot so I edited a little bit . I hope you dont mind

Comment: I simplified the actual actions I was taking for the sake of asking the question - I'm using a prepared statement; the issue I was experiencing was due to the way I was handling merging an array of the parameter types with an array of the parameter values. Marked your answer as correct, as this touches on some important notes for someone with an issue like the one I posted about. Great response!

Answer (score -1):

This colname column, see if it's like if a string use like this:

```
  $mysqli->query("UPDATE table_name SET colname='{$array}' WHERE somecol='someval'");
```